# what's the type of 'print' in python

Tags: python

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul 27 2016, 16:11:41) 
[GCC 5.4.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> type(print)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    type(print)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

In python, all is object, why does type(print) occur above error?

Answer (score 11):

In Python 2, print is a statement. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/.
Not all is object. For example, `if`, `else`, `for`... are not. These ones are also language keywords and cannot be used as variable names.

In Python 3 however, print() is a function, so it is an object too.

Answer (score 3):

`print` is one of [simple statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html). It's not an object, therefore it cannot have a type. Similarly, `return` or `break` also does not have a type.

Answer (score -2):

This is what my terminal told me.

```
>>> type(list)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(print)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>>
```

Comment: You are in Python 3. OP uses Python 2.7.12.